# Execute Javascript before Page_Load method of Visual Web Part in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

> I need to get screen size and depending upon result need to display
>   images on page.  Code of ascx.cs file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 0;
    width = screen.width;

    $('#<%= clientScreenWidth.ClientID %>').val(width);
    alert(width); </script>  
 <asp:HiddenField ID="clientScreenWidth" runat="server" />
```

> on .cs file in Page_Load method I am trying to access value of Hiddenfield but value is " ",
>   as javascipt will run once page is loaded.  Is there a way to force
>   javascript to run before page loads. I can see many such Questions on
>   StackOverFlow and Blogs but nothing is working as I am working with
>   sharepoint 2010 and don't have tags like `<body>` and all.

Answer (score 1):

Page_Load will always call before script logs, you need to drop a time in your web part with a loading message and in Timer_Tick bind your sharepoint web part. That way you will get data in hidden field.

If you want to know the better way to do it, visit: http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would display/hide the images with JavaScript as that is when you will have the screen size information and it won't require another round trip to the server.

If you want to continue with the logic in C# you can have the JS initiate a postback after assigning the field, reload part of the page with an ajax call or reload the page with a query string added. All of these however require another round trip to the server.

Answer (score 0):

try putting your  below the   In your example, you are referencing something that doesn't even exist yet.